# Old $(window).scroll function suddenly not working - moving up two variables corrects it?

Tags: jquery, scroll

I've been using the function below for quite some time now and it's been working smoothly and as inteded. However, when i went back to check the status of the website today, i realised that it wasn't working any longer. Using the console.log it appeared that the variables `thresholdCrossed` and `thresholdCrossedTop` was being updated before the function that comes before them, even though they are placed below this in the function context. How can this be?

Moving the two beforementioned variables up and into the end of that function which should otherwise have been executed before updated the variables solved the issue.

**This is the old version:**

```
jQuery.fn.followTo = function () {
    var $this = this;

  jQuery(window).scroll(function(e){
    var scroll = jQuery(window).scrollTop();

    jQuery(function (){
      if(!thresholdCrossedTop && scroll > containerOffsetTop  && scroll < pos) {
        // custom function here
      }
      else if (!thresholdCrossed && scroll > pos) {
        // custom function here
      } 
      else if (thresholdCrossed && scroll <= pos) {
        // custom function here
      }
      else if(thresholdCrossedTop && scroll <= containerOffsetTop) {
        // custom function here
      };
    });
    thresholdCrossed = scroll > pos;       // Was updating too soon
    thresholdCrossedTop = scroll > containerOffsetTop;     // Was updating too soon
  });
};

jQuery('#indhold-inner').followTo(indholdHeight);
```

**This is the fixed version:**

```
jQuery.fn.followTo = function () {
    var $this = this;

  jQuery(window).scroll(function(e){
    var scroll = jQuery(window).scrollTop();

    jQuery(function (){
      if(!thresholdCrossedTop && scroll > containerOffsetTop  && scroll < pos) {
        // custom function here
      }
      else if (!thresholdCrossed && scroll > pos) {
        // custom function here
      } 
      else if (thresholdCrossed && scroll <= pos) {
        // custom function here
      }
      else if(thresholdCrossedTop && scroll <= containerOffsetTop) {
        // custom function here
      };
      thresholdCrossed = scroll > pos;       // moved up
      thresholdCrossedTop = scroll > containerOffsetTop;     // moved up
    });
  });
};

jQuery('#indhold-inner').followTo(indholdHeight);
```

Initially I was wondering whether it had to do with an update in Chrome or something, causing the scripts to run async (I have no idea..), but I tested in IE 11 as well and the same behaviour was apparent here.

Comment: You are nesting document ready event inside window scroll event, you shouldn't do that. I guess the behaviour you are facing has more to do with some different jQuery version than with any browser version. If i remember it correctly, there was change in jq3.x (or even 2.x) regarding the pseudo ready function. EDIT: so as a fix to test, remove `jQuery(function (){}` wrapper

Comment: @A.Wolff My god, I think you're right! I recently updated from 1.9.x to 3.1.1 and completely forgot about it / didn't consider it. Further I actually had no idea that the `jQuery(function(){..` was a shorthand for `$(document).ready()` so thank you for letting me know! If you want you can add this as an answer and I will check it as correct as it's the right answer to this complication.

Comment: I guess this is because change regarding ready states in jq3.x now being async. `If you want you can add this as an answer` i'd prefer to let other guy making a complete answer because actually i don't have enough time in hand. Anyway, this should give some info: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/3197

Comment: Really great to know - I've tried deleting the ready function and it works like a charm again - so definitely the reason. That just proves the value of reading up on the changes you implement ;)